# Exception in Site.createExternalUser in Apex RESTclass: Site.ExternalUserCreateException: [That operation is only allowed from within an active site.]

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-communities

I have a Non-Salesforce Auth System which holds usernames and passwords for a few thousand users. I am willing to migrate these users to Salesforce and give access to these users to my Experience Cloud site. I am developing an apex REST Resource which will take username and password as arguments and create a user with that username and password with a community profile. I am planning to call this API from my Non-Salesforce system and migrate all these users. I am using Site.createExternalUser method in this API. I am getting the exception
`Site.ExternalUserCreateException: [That operation is only allowed from within an active site.]`
The reason I am using Site.createExternalUser is because I don't want to send the welcome email/reset password email to my users since they already have signed up successfully long ago.
I am open to any alternatives for achiving this.
Below is my code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/createUser/*')
global with sharing class createUserRestResource {
     @HttpPost
     global static String doPost(){
            Contact con=new Contact();
            con.Firstname="First";
            con.LastName= "Last";
            con.Email="first.last@example.com";
            con.AccountId='/Add an account Id here./';
            insert con;
            
            usr.Username= "usernameFromRequest@example.com";
            usr.Alias= "alias123";
            usr.Email= "first.last@example.com";
            usr.FirstName= "First";
            usr.IsActive= true;
            usr.LastName= "Last";
            usr.ProfileId='/Community User Profile Id/';
            usr.EmailEncodingKey= 'ISO-8859-1';
            usr.TimeZoneSidKey= 'America/Los_Angeles';
            usr.LocaleSidKey= 'en_US';
            usr.LanguageLocaleKey= 'en_US';
            usr.ContactId = con.Id;
             
            String userId = Site.createExternalUser(usr, con.AccountId, 'Password@1234', false);
            return userId;
     }
}
```

Comment: Consider posting on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ too

Comment: You need to use the site domain and not the org domain when you call the API endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress sending emails out in whole org (Setup -> Deliverability) or in the Community config there will be way to not send welcome emails ([your community -> Workspaces -> Administration -> Emails](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_customize_email.htm&type=5)).

Without running on actual Site I don't think you can pull it off in one go. In theory it's simple, insert contact, then insert user. In practice depends which fields you set on the user. If it's Partner community you might be setting UserRoleId too and that's forbidden. See [MIXED DML](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm) error. In Customer community you might be safe... until you decide to assign them some permission sets too.

You might need 2 separate endpoints, 1 to create contact, 1 to make user out of it. Or save the contact and then offload user creation to @future/Queueable/something else like that.